# Is $("<tr>") a valid selector?

Tags: jquery

I understand that the general pattern of jQuery is to select DOM elements then to operate on them. Selection is by using a selector like so:

```
$( "div.foo" )
```

I am currently studying some code and found this:

```
var buttons = $("<tr>").addClass("buttons").append("<td>")
```

and

```
var db_name = $("<input name='db_name' type='text' placeholder='Enter db name     here'>").val(_db_name);
```

Have been searching high and low for an answer but can't understand why $("") works when a correct selector should not include the angular brackets.

Can I ask if there is another way to write selectors that have angular brackets which is why the code worked?

Comment: No. It's *not* a valid [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) (it's accepted, but is *not* a selector).

Comment: *"Have been searching high and low for an answer..."* [**Really?**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Yes - from "Learning jQuery by Chaffer/Swedberg (2011)", "jQuery Reference Guide by Chaffer/Swedberg (2007)", "Extending jQuery by Wood (2013)" and "http://api.jquery.com/". Problem is you can't really search for this sort of thing: there is no key term I can use. Searched "$("<" and yield no results. So I have to pore thru systematically thru each chapter to find something relevant. Mayb you can suggest a better place to look for an answer rather than doubt my effort. Part of being new to the subject is also not knowing where to look for the correct answers.

Comment: @user2349806: I **did** suggest a better place to look (I even linked to it): The official, easily-found documentation of the library you're using. That would be the first or second place to look when "...searching high and low..." and it directly addresses your question. This is no different from Joe saying to Mary: "I couldn't find the phone number for the pizza place, I searched high and low." And Mary saying "Did you look in the phone book?" And Joe looking sheepish. :-)

Answer (score 6):

`$("<tr>")` is not a selector, it creates a new `tr` element look st the documentation for [jQuery(html)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Your code `var buttons = $("<tr>").addClass("buttons").append("<td>")` creates a new `tr` element with class buttons and adds a `td` element to it. But note that it is not added to the document(it is still only a in memory dom object)

You need to add the `buttons` object to a table if you want to see it in your page

Comment: Random vaguely-related question: What if I had an ID with the value `<td>` (okay, it's a terrible [but valid HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) ID) - but how could I select on it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If the argument string contains the angle brackets then it creates a new element, which you can then manipulate or add to the dom:

```
$("<tr>").addClass('row').appendTo('#table');
```

Without the brackets it's a selector, which selects an element from the DOM.

If you check the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) these are the two differences we are seeing:

```
// selects an element
jQuery( selector [, context ] )

// creates an element
jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )
```

Comment: Also thanks mysterious stranger who just pushed me over 10k :)